# Can't make successful connection to mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql

So the purpose of this database is to execute the queries needed for a website that will be accessing this, here is the code:

```
package dodRus;
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect_Database {
 // JDBC driver name and database URL
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/?user=root";

 //  Database credentials
 static final String USER = "root";
 static final String PASS = ;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 try{
    //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //STEP 3: Open a connection
   System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
   conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

   //STEP 4: Execute a query
    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql;
    sql = "INSERT INTO Inventory " + "VALUES (shirt,1234,5)";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);


 }catch(SQLException se){
    //Handle errors for JDBC
    se.printStackTrace();
 }catch(Exception e){
//Handle errors for Class.forName
    e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
    //finally block used to close resources
    try{
       if(stmt!=null)
          stmt.close();
    }catch(SQLException se2){
    }// nothing we can do
    try{
       if(conn!=null)
          conn.close();
    }catch(SQLException se){
       se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try
  }//end try

}
 }
```

and here is the error:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2975)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1600)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1695)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3020)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1074)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:1008)
>     at dodRus.Connect_Database.main(Connect_Database.java:30)
> ```

Obviously it is not making a successful connection to the database but I can't figure out why

Comment: I really hope you did NOT post the real root password in your example code...

Comment: Even if it's localhost, still not a good idea to post it

Comment: Anyways you never specified the database name you are going to use in your url. Error says it right there. url should be `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/(database name here)?user=root`

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the database name in your DSN string.

```
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/<name_of_database>?user=" + USER + "&password=" + PASS;
```

See the [Connector/J documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).